# SailsJS not loading my assets

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I can't understand why the SailsJS is not loading the my assets, can someone explain if I am missing something?

I am using the tags although nothing happens

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

my EJS markup is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test Dashboard</h1>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to give more details, by default all the stuff in your assets folder can be accessed with url localhost:xxx/. JS files in assets/js/ can be accessed with url localhost:xxxx/js/ etc. Is it not accessable?

Comment: Neither, I. ALL I WANT TO DO is add a script tag `<script src="js/dependencies/sails.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` OR `<script src="js/alert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` to a view JUST TO TEST getting a hold of an asset so I can move onto accessing scripts from Sails with my Ionic app. I'll deal with CORS later if necessary -- but right now I can not do the MOST BASIC of starting an app. I'm close to giving up on Sails but it holds a lot of promise (namely RESTful WebSockets). This a huge hickup, or a terrible framework. Please help us! SOS!